# Why do we perform this ritual at someone's death bed?

Tags: rituals, death, ganga, tulasi

When a person is about to die and leave his mortal body it is said that we must put **gangajal** i.e. water of holy river Ganga and **tulsipatra** i.e. leaves of sacred Tulsi plant in the person's mouth. What is the significance of this ritual? Is it necessary to do this? Does this have any scientific significance as well?

Comment: The answer is in a purana which describes the importance of tulsi leaves and if someone dies with tulsi in his mouth then he attains heavens.The puran also says that at the time of dead the person should not die with naked ears and so people use to blow air.

Comment: @PravinRGMishra what is the meaning of naked ears

Comment: Pls keep in mind that asking for scientific reasons is not allowed here .. it might lead to the Q's closure

Comment: @Rickross I have asked scientific evidence just as an extended question. My main motive was to know the reason why this ritual is carried out

Comment: Ok but asking for scientific reasons is not allowed .. I m just trying to inform u about that (in case u already do not know) @codeczar

Comment: @codeczar means no wearings in the ears.I will let you know the purana aur tantra source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Brahmavaivata-Purana (Madhya, 26/59)

> gangA-narAyanakshetre pivan gangAjalam narah/ Ganga-Gangeti sriNvanto mrito vA kim na sAdhayet// 
> meaning that taking Ganga-water  at the time of death gives all the possible virtues.

In the Agastya-Samhita we get

> mukhasthA tulasi yasya nirvANa-padadAyini (7) 
> meaning that tulasi-leaf kept in the mouth liberates an individual.

So giving ganga-jal and tulasi-patra is advised at the time of death by the holy scriptures.

I do not think science has anything to do here. There  is no concept of virtue or liberation in science and that is I hope is known to all!

Comment: is there any scientific reason as well

Comment: Wait for a few more years/decades, scientists will figure it out

Comment: Scientific reasons, even if there are some, can not be discussed in answers because that amounts to scientific speculation, and which is not allowed  here @codeczar

Comment: @codeczar, do you ask for scientific reason when doctor gives you a headache medicine, or do you simply pop it int your mouth because you trust that the doctor and the pharmaceutical industry did enough research beforehand ? similarly, we trust that the rishis (scientists of ancient Bharat) did lot more research and gave us these medicines like Ganga jal and Tulsi.